# What is the bare essential for the PLB slave module in FPGA?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

WHat I only need is to be able to read/write to the slave registers of my custom IP and be able send a software reset and give clock to my custom IP module. What can I exclude from the bus signals so to be able to insert more ports for my custom IP, in overcoming the limitation of the IOBs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you can't leave out anything.  There's a very good reason it's called a bus standard.

Write you logic in Verilog or VHDL and then just use the EDK import peripheral tool and you're done.

Make your peripheral as simple as you want/need it. The tool will properly wrap it in the bus logic and provide the necessary files for the /data directory of your pcore.

All the seeminly "extra" connections really don't cost you any chip-area or performance.  But leave the wrong thing out and you'll spend weeks trying to sort out the mess.